# Less strict mode for uninitialized variables in when compiling typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I used a fork of angular-cli which compiles multiple modules https://www.npmjs.com/package/hydra-ngtools-webpack Everything works as expected in aot, But when I compile in JIT I get an error ..

> *Cannot read push of undefined*

I traced the error to this line in angular_compiler_plugin.js under the @ngtools/webpack folder. As you can see lazyRoutes has not be given an initial value.

```
_listLazyRoutesFromProgram() {
    let lazyRoutes;
    if (this._JitMode) {
        if (!this.entryModule) {
            return {};
        }
        const ngProgram = compiler_cli_1.createProgram({
            rootNames: this._rootNames,
            options: Object.assign({}, this._compilerOptions, { genDir: '', collectAllErrors: true }),
            host: this._compilerHost,
        });
        this.entryModule.forEach((entryModule) => {
            ngProgram.listLazyRoutes(entryModule.path + '#' + entryModule.className).forEach((lazyRoute) => {
                lazyRoutes.push(lazyRoute);
            });
        });
    }
```

If I initialize it like this

```
let lazyRoutes=[];
```

The build compiles without an error. I have contacted the author for the this package for the source of this repo so I can make a pull request and still waiting to hear from him. Is there a way I can tell the compiler not to complain about this uninitialized variable and be forgiving. Otherwise I will have to edit this line on every npm install which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a disable statement for TS Lintt like so:

```
_listLazyRoutesFromProgram() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:RULENAME
    let lazyRoutes;
    if (this._JitMode)
    ...
```

you still have to add it to the code so might not really save you much.